# Why are there no attempts to establish the metric system in the US?

Tags: united-states, international-standards

As far is I'm aware, there aren't many rational arguments for using the imperial system of measurement in favor of the metric system.

Have there been actual political attempts to establish the metric system in the US? Why not?

Comment: There have been efforts to switch the US to the metric system going back to [Thomas Jefferson in 1793](https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2017/12/28/574044232/how-pirates-of-the-caribbean-hijacked-americas-metric-system). Are you interested in the _modern_ arguments agains full metric conversion?

Comment: You need to expand your awareness, then :-)  There are many ways in which the US system of units is better for everyday use than the metric system.  For just one example, US units for volume go by powers of 2, rather than 10.

Comment: all foods in the US are labeled with metric units. all cars sold in the US have to be able to display kph. Seconds and amperes are arguably well-established as well.

Comment: @divibisan I was indeed also curious about the modern discussion about it. But considering DonFusili 's answer, I realise there is simply no need to "enforce" the metric system further.

Comment: @jamesqf You are probably correct about the lack of my awareness in this regard, hence the question. Although I don't quite see how the example you mentioned is an advantage per se, as it doesn't make volume objectively more comprehensible.

Comment: @Jan The only argument I've heard in favor of customary units is that the smaller Fahrenheit degrees have more useful intervals in normal environmental temperatures (ie. talking about the 40's, 60's, or 70's in terms of weather is more meaningful than the 20's in Celsius)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All imperial units used in the US today are legally defined in terms of metric units since 1983.

The US officially uses the metric system as the "preferred system of weights and measures" since President Ford signed the [Metric Conversion Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_Conversion_Act) in 1975.

Further active 'metrication' of the US was [abolished by Reagan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Metric_Board) in 1982.

As such, there is no need to establish the metric system, it's already established.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrication_in_the_United_States has a bit more information.

Comment: While technically correct, it's really a stretch to say that the metric system is already established in the US just because a gallon is officially defined as 3.785411784 L